# Replicate one db into another on same server and same instance in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, database-replication

I just want to replicate a db into another on same machine and same mysql instance. 
is it possible..??
i have tried but not working as all

```
server-id       = 1
report_host = master-is-slave-host
log_bin          = /var/log/mysqld/mysql-bin.log
relay_log                =     /var/log/mysqld/relay-bin
replicate-same-server-id = 1
binlog_do_db = replication_1
replicate_rewrite_db = replication_1->replication_2
replicate_do_table = replication_1.table1
replicate_do_table = replication_2.table2
```

Comment: Specifically, what have you tried doing?

Comment: i have two db replication_1 and replication_2, and i want that if replication_1    changes  then the same changes will automatically done in replication_2.